# Implement google earth in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am implementing one iphone applicaiton in which I want to implement google earth.

I have done research on net for google earth for if any google earth api available or not.

But I have not found sucess.

Can you advice me is it possible to implement google earth in our applciation.

Please advice me for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need Google Earth or Google Maps?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest downloading the Google Earth app from:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-earth/id293622097?mt=8

However, if you still want to build an app, the Google Earth API documentation lies at:

http://code.google.com/apis/earth/

Comment: Thanks for reply..This application is not available of Indian store so I cant download..And this above api is for browser not for iPhone....Can you give me other idea for that

Comment: I do not know of any other source now. I will look for it.

Answer (score -3):

Google does not provide any API specifically for iPhone. This API is in JavaScript.

[Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/earth)

Comment: No, you can't. Google Earth for browsers requires a plugin.